# Timeout on a HTTP request in python

Tags: python, httpwebrequest

Very occasionally when making a http request, I am waiting for an age for a response that never comes.  What is the recommended way to cancel this request after a reasonable period of time?

Comment: What code are you using to make the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the HTTP request timeout.

Comment: I must be pretty tired, not to think to look there first, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The timeout parameter to [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), or [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection). The original urllib has no such convenient feature. You can also use an asynchronous HTTP client such as [twisted.web.client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.html), but that's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a lot of HTTP requests, you can change this globally by calling [socket.setdefaulttimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout)

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this because it seems that the timeout parameter was only added in python 2.6 and I need to support 2.5 as. well